# Connect R to local sql server using RSQLServer package

Tags: r, sql-server-2012, dplyr, rstudio

I am trying to connect R and local sql server i.e. windows authentication based using dplyr package as I have large data set to work upon and cannot pull all of them into R. Can someone please help me with the connection.

I believe `RSQLServer::src_sqlserver` under RSQLServer package would help but I am not able to do so.

I tried using this command:

```
install_github('rsqlserver', 'agstudy',args = '--no-multiarch')
```

but I get an error message

> :ERROR:
>   dependency 'rClr' is not available for package 'rsqlserver'.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

the error message you got is caused by the inability to install a the rClr package. 
however - you can try the following method:

a. install package 'RODBC' from cran and attach it:

`install.packages("RODBC")`

`library("RODBC")`

b. define a connection: (change to your server's IP or localhost)

`connection <- odbcDriverConnect("driver=SQL Server; server=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX; database=[your db name]; trusted_connection=true")`

c. type your query using the defined connection:

`sqlQuery(connection  , 'select * from information_schema.tables')`

cool?

Comment: Hey, I want the connection to run dplyr function directly on the local database instead of pulling the entire data frame into R. Hence require a RSqlserver package for this.

Comment: why? what exactly are you trying to do? what functionality?

Comment: I am working on a large data set and cannot pull the entire data frame so I want to use the dplyr package for data wrangling on the complete data.

Comment: The link has it all but am unable to execute the same as the package is not getting installed.                           https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.r-bloggers.com/accessing-mssql-server-with-r-rsqlserver-with-dplyr/amp/

Comment: if you wanna query the db in anyway, you can use RODBC as suggested. I don't know about dplyr functionality but i suspect it has nothing to do with the connection method. you can also use dplyr with it. maybe there is something I'm missing imho but using dplyr as a DB is redundant if you're connected to SQL DB. the data resides on the DB and not in memory on both cases\

Comment: I do not want to load the entire table into R as a data frame and run a dplyr query.